# Unable to ping any website through terminal and network utility

Tags: terminal, network, vpn, internet, ping

I have internet connection and I can access every website. But when I try to ping any website ( be it www.google.com or www.stackoverflow.com or any site ) I always get `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` (I tried to ping and traceroute from terminal as well as network utility but faced the same issue). Moreover if I try to ping any website which is on VPN then I get correct response ( All packet transmitted and all received no loss )

I am on VPN and behind proxy too.

What can be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe is your proxy blocking ICMP packages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely pings are blocked somewhere upstream from you.

Comment: Okay, so what can be done? Remember that I have full access to internet.

Comment: Well, in this case you actually don't have "full access to the Internet," you have somewhat limited access to the Internet since pings are being blocked by your network administrator. You can try to connect from a different network, or ask your network administrator to make a change.

Comment: but I am accessing internet right now and pings are blocked?

Comment: The Internet is not the same thing as the World Wide Web (the web runs on the Internet), and depending on your network configuration, you can have access to any arbitrary portion of the Internet. So, it may look like you can access any web site and/or retrieve your email, or even ping some sites, but that doesn't necessarily imply anything about accessing any other portion of the Internet, including pinging other hosts.